# Probability that Amy, Bill and Poor pete win money 6.042 MIT

Tags: probability

I was doing the following problem:

> Problem 2. [12 points] Amy, Bill, and Poor Pete play a game:
>
> 1. Each player puts \$2 on the table.
> 2. Each player secretly writes a number between 1 and 4.
> 3. They roll a fair, four-sided die with faces numbered 1, 2, 3, and 4.
> 4. The money on the table is divided among the players that guessed correctly. If no one guessed correctly, then everyone gets their
>      money back and Poor Pete is paid \$0.25 in “service fees”.
>
>    Suppose that, Amy and Bill cheat by picking a pair of distinct
>      numbers uniformly at random.

How do you calculate the following Probability:

> Pete guesses right AND either Amy or Bill guesses right?

I think it should be a simple question but I can't seem to get the answer $\frac{1}{8}$

---

This is what I have tried:

Let P denote the event that Pete wins, A and B that Amy and Bill will respectively.

So we want $Pr[P=wins \cap (A=wins \cup B=wins)]$ which is equal to:

$Pr[P=wins]Pr[(A=wins \cup B=wins)]$

So I tried calculating each one by writing down the tree corresponding to each Pr and then multiplying the probability.

Pr[P = wins] = Pr[P chooses the same as the number in the real die] = Pr[1 came up]Pr[Pete chooses 1]+ Pr[2 came up]Pr[Pete chooses 2] + Pr[3 came up]Pr[Pete chooses 3] + Pr[4 came up]Pr[Pete chooses 4] = $\frac{4}{16} = \frac{1}{4}$

The other probability $Pr[(A=wins \cup B=wins)]$ I was simply going to compute via inclusion exclusion. i.e.

$$Pr[(A=wins \cup B=wins)] = Pr[A=wins] + Pr[B = wins] - Pr[(A=wins \cap B=wins)]$$

is this approach correct? Can't seem to make it work and give me $\frac{1}{8}$.

I also had to compute:

> Pete guesses right AND both Amy and Bill guess wrong
>
> Pete guesses wrong AND either Amy or Bill guesses right
>
> Pete guesses wrong AND both Amy and Bill guess wrong

and was wondering if this general approach was correct.

Comment: You got most of the way there, but you're just missing the last line of the problem: _Suppose that, Amy and Bill cheat by picking a pair of distinct numbers uniformly at random._ This implies they never pick the same number.

Comment: @aes after thinking about it more, I think I am confused on how to compute the intersection...

Comment: If they always choose different numbers, can they ever both win? Even if that comment helps, it would be good to understand what _a pair of distinct numbers at random_ means. I'll post a short answer discussing this.

Comment: I think I just realized a misconception I had, they only roll one die, not three for each person right? Like, each person doesn't get to guess for each of their dices...because they are only 1 die. I think ur trying to say Probability of intersection is zero...right?

Comment: finall,ur right, thats why u get 1/8. Thanks! no wonder this question seemed so bizarre to me...

Comment: Yes, they only roll one die, and each compare against it.

Answer (score 1):

You've understood Pete's behavior well, as well as the independence of Pete's behavior and that of Amy & Bill's. But you haven't explored Amy & Bill's behavior.

The key is to understand what *a pair of distinct numbers at random* means.

Amy and Bill, as a pair, select one of:

$\begin{array}{cc}
\text{Amy} & \text{Bill} \\
1 & 2 \\
1 & 3 \\
1 & 4 \\
2 & 1 \\
2 & 3 \\
2 & 4 \\
3 & 1 \\
3 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
4 & 1 \\
4 & 2 \\
4 & 3
\end{array}$

And they, as a pair, select each with equal probability. There are twelve, so the selection given in each row has probability $1/12$.

Then $P[\text{A wins}] = 1/4$ (sum over the four possibilities as you did for Pete: $P[A = 1] = 3/12 = 1/4$, etc) and $P[\text{B wins}] = 1/4$, but $P[\text{A wins and B wins}] = 0$.